# ACA IRS status service response with errors

Tags: irs

Would it be possible for somebody provide me with example of the ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus web service response  with errors?
I would like to see structure of the attached(if it's in attachment) errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for sample data and not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an XML with rejection errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:FormBCTransmitterSubmissionDtl xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:ns3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095BCtransmittermessage">
<ACATransmitterSubmissionDetail>
    <TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
        <SubmissionLevelStatusCd>Rejected</SubmissionLevelStatusCd>
        <UniqueSubmissionId>1095C-16-0000XXXX|1</UniqueSubmissionId>
    </TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
    <TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
        <UniqueSubmissionId>1095C-16-0000XXXX|1</UniqueSubmissionId>
        <ns2:ErrorMessageDetail>
            <ns2:ErrorMessageCd>AIREX126</ns2:ErrorMessageCd>
            <ns2:ErrorMessageTxt>Rejected submission - TIN Validation Failed for ALE Member's EIN</ns2:ErrorMessageTxt>
            <ns2:XpathContent>EmployerEIN</ns2:XpathContent>
        </ns2:ErrorMessageDetail>
    </TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
    <TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
        <UniqueRecordId>1095C-16-0000XXXX|1|3</UniqueRecordId>
        <ns2:ErrorMessageDetail>
            <ns2:ErrorMessageCd>AIRTN500</ns2:ErrorMessageCd>
            <ns2:ErrorMessageTxt>TIN Validation Failed</ns2:ErrorMessageTxt>
        </ns2:ErrorMessageDetail>
    </TransmitterErrorDetailGrp>
</ACATransmitterSubmissionDetail>
</ns3:FormBCTransmitterSubmissionDtl>
```

You can recreate that same error response by sending invalid EIN's and SSN's that AATS doesn't expect.

If you want to send valid test EIN's, TIN's and names (outside of the IRS AATS test scenarios), please refer to https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5164.pdf (starting at page 6).

Sample range of valid test EIN's:

```
EIN RANGE                        NAME CONTROL
00-0000001 through 00-0000100    HELP
00-0000101 through 00-0000200    HIDE
```

Sample range of valid test SSN's:

```
SSN RANGE                        NAME CONTROL
000-00-0001 through 000-00-0100  HERR
000-00-0101 through 000-00-0200  MART
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed! Is it comes as MTOM attachment?

Comment: Yes, it comes MTOM attached. If you are debugging your soap messages in 'fine' or 'debug' level, you'll also see the data inside the <code>BulkExchangeFile</code> response is the base46-encoded version of the attachment.